# How to limit files used for validation accuracy with TensorFlow Estimator?

Tags: validation, input, tensorflow

I am training a model in TensorFlow, using an Estimator `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`. When calling estimator.fit, I also pass a Validation Monitor `tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor` with an input function. This input function uses the `tf.TFRecordReader` reader function plugged into a batch generator `tf.contrib.learn.io.read_batch_features`. It is programmed to swipe one epoch when calling it for validation, by setting `num_epochs` to `1` as `read_batch_features argument`.

Is there a way to limit the size of the validation test set without having to delete files in the validation directory?
E.g. if I have 100k records in the directory that I pass to the batch reader, what is the easiest way to limit the amount of files it uses as validation, to say e.g. 1k?

This is all in the assumption that read_batch_features actually does swipe the whole validation directory when doing an evaluation step. I think this assumption is correct, since I am now using a simple hack by putting a * in the input directory (e.g. `input_dir=FLAGS.input_dir + "/test_examples-001*"` will limit the files used). It would be nice to have a cleaner way, such that I can precisely specify the amount of files used for validation.